# Squid proxy at ubuntu 18.04 impossible to connect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04, http-proxy, squid

I'm new with Google Cloud so I may explain not precise.\
I have VM with Ubuntu 18.04 at Google Cloud Platform and I have installed Squid 3 proxy server on it.
Proxy is already configured a little.

```
http_port 3128 transparent
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
auth_param basic children 2
auth_param basic realm My Proxy Server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 24 hours
auth_params basic casesensitive off

#add acl rules
acl users proxy_auth REQUIRED

#http access rules
http_access deny !users
http_access allow users
```

In Google console I can see server's outer IP address but It does not work through it.

The **ifconfig** command shows next

```
ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.156.0.3  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fe9c:3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 42:01:0a:9c:00:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 104399  bytes 83418274 (83.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93840  bytes 12598292 (12.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16697  bytes 1149429 (1.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16697  bytes 1149429 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

where **inet 10.156.0.3** means my inner IP.
I suppose I don't understand some simple rule of work with Google Platform or just with proxy configuration.

May you show me where I'm wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you open port 3128 at the firewall to make connections to your VM possible?

Comment: It seems I didn't. Thank you for a tip I will check it right now.

Comment: I provided more details in my answer. Please mark it as accepted if you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue you need to check with [nmap](https://nmap.org/) which ports are open on your VM and if 3128 is closed set `Network tag` for your VM and add firewall rule to allow access to it.

I've tried to replicate your issue on my test VM:

1. create VM instance or use existing one
2. install Squid
3. check if Squid is running:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl status squid 
    ● squid.service - LSB: Squid HTTP Proxy version 3.x
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/squid; generated)
      **Active: active (running)** since Wed 2020-02-19 11:47:50 UTC; 26s ago
   ```
4. check accessibility to Squid with nmap:

   ```
   $ nmap -Pn 35.XXX.155.XXX
   Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-02-19 12:53 CET
   ...
   Host is up (0.023s latency).
   Not shown: 996 filtered ports
   PORT     STATE  SERVICE
   22/tcp   open   ssh
   3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
   8000/tcp closed http-alt
   8081/tcp closed blackice-icecap
   ```

   Squid is not available
5. edit VM and set `Network tag` `proxy-server`
6. add firewall rule to enable connections to Squid by using `Network tag`:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute --project=test-prj firewall-rules create proxy-server-rule --direction=INGRESS --priority=999 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:3128 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=proxy-server
   ```
7. check accessibility to Squid with nmap again

   ```
   $ nmap -Pn 35.XXX.155.XXX
   Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-02-19 12:53 CET
   ...
   Host is up (0.022s latency).
   Not shown: 995 filtered ports
   PORT     STATE  SERVICE
   22/tcp   open   ssh
   3128/tcp open   squid-http
   3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
   8000/tcp closed http-alt
   8081/tcp closed blackice-icecap
   ```

   now Squid is ready to use.

Comment: I have used your advice but It seems it impossible to perform this through SSH at my account. I got next message:
`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.` Then I tried to do this via console with yours parameters. [link]http://prntscr.com/r4q5mm  But even this way **nmap** shows: `Host is up (0.0020s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  closed https
3128/tcp closed squid-http
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server`

Comment: You can create the same rule via UI interface. Have a look at this guide https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules.

Comment: I made it via UI. [link]http://prntscr.com/r4sl01 but my selected ports are still closed:`3128/tcp closed squid-http`

Comment: At the screenshot firewall rule looks good. Does it have lowest priority? Why you didn't use `Network tag`?  It's not mandatory, but it's useful. I've checked in my example with default Squid config and no firewall at VM. Try to check with default Squid config and turn off firewall at VM if you use it. Also, try to connect to Squid and provide output here.

Comment: I created a new instance and made a firewall rule via UI for 3128 and 587 ports. **nmap** started to show those ports but they were closed.(I have not configured firewall at VM)

Comment: Did you use `Network tag?` For test it'll be better to set only 3128 port.

Comment: Then I adden in squid.conf few strings: `acl Safe_ports port 3128
acl Safe_ports port 587` and it caused  opening for only 3128 port. **nmap** shows `587/tcp  closed submission
3128/tcp open   squid-http` and I can not use it as proxy in browser

Comment: yes I created a `proxy-server` tag and that rule a associated with it

Comment: **1.** Do you have any other rules in GCP firewal with priority 999 or less? If yes, change priority for your test VM with Squid to make less than the smallest one. **2.** Do you have a few ports in the in GCP firewal rule for your test VM? If yes, change it and keep anly 3128 or even try to open all tcp ports by selecting tcp without specifying any ports. **3.** Do you change squid.conf or other configuration settings? If yes, delete test item and create new one by following my steps, but do not change anything inside VM to get the same configuration as mine.

Comment: **1.** My rule for 3128 port is lowest(999). Other for http and https have 1000 and other default have 65534.
**2.** Now there is only 3128 port.
**3.** I made new instance with only squid instaled and `proxy-server` tag.

Comment: Okay, everything looks good. So, let's proceed with `nmap -Pn EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM` from your premises. Also, try to use Squid proxy and check inside your instance log file with command `tail -f /var/log/squid3/access.log`.

Comment: **nmap** shows that 3128 port is open

string from `sudo tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log`:

`1582191844.819      0 [MY IP ADDRESS] TCP_DENIED/403 4032 CONNECT www.google.com: 443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html`

Comment: Okay, finally we've got some positive result. So, rule that you put into GCP **firewall works as expected**, and **you're able to reach your Squid proxy** and the next step is configuring your Squid proxy. As possible quick temporally workaround you can check squid.conf and replace `http_access deny all` with `http_access allow all` like in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051554/squid-tcp-denied-403-4037-get-http-detectportal-firefox-com-success-txt-hier

Comment: Congrats! Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: Why did you change your mind and unset accepted flag from my answer? I thought we solved your issue. Please let me know. If my answer solved your issue please mark it back as accepted.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't use this service very often and misunderstood the interface. My problem is completely resolved. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Thank you!